# URL Codeigniter - pass a string

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I want to specify the routing rule for URL `/responder/1/type/2/category/3/...`, that in controller i could get string `/responder/1/type/2/category/3/...` and cut this string:

```
[0] = responder;
[1] = 1;
[2] = type;
[3] = 2;
```

and .etc.
The amount of URL settings can be infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the URI class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

You can get the URL segments as an array by calling the `segment_array()` method in your controller:

```
//get the URI segments
$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
```